# Why can not find module 'jade'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using node.js with Express 4.13.3

and when I run my file, I keep get error said

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jade'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at new View (/Users/alatebloomer/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:78:30)
at EventEmitter.render (/Users/alatebloomer/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
at ServerResponse.render (/Users/alatebloomer/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
at /Users/alatebloomer/WebstormProjects/Node_for_Beginner/filename.js:20:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/alatebloomer/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/alatebloomer/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
```

Here is my filename.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/myroute', function(req, res){
  res.send('This is GET method');
  res.end();
});

app.post('/myroutee', function(req, res){
  res.send('This is POST method');
  res.end();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('mypage', {msg1: "Hello world!"});
});

app.listen(12345);
```

and here is my page.jade

```
html
   head
       title Hello Jade
   body
       div
           h1 hello #{msg1}
```

I already install jade by "npm install jade -g"

Did I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
npm install jade --save
npm install
```

Comment: I think the top command in isolation should work. Essentially, I think Jade needs to be a local module to the project.

Comment: Thanks. i use first command and it works.However, the second command will show error said "Couldn't read dependencies".

Comment: @aBloomer check your package.json file syntax if "Couldn't read dependencies" error raised

Comment: Where can I find this file?

Comment: @aBloomer in the root of you node.js project

Comment: I find it under jade folder.

Comment: @aBloomer no, jade has own dependencies and package.json file. Your dependencies in package.json file, located in one level with node_modules (root of project)

Comment: I canot find any package.json file except one under jade folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90255/discussion-between-andrew-paramoshkin-and-abloomer).

Comment: Thanks a lot man for sharing this, really nothing was working for me very good answer (y)